# Giving error in virtual function

Tags: c++, error-handling, virtual-functions

Consider two geometries `Triangle` and `Line` which inherit from base structure `Geometry`. Derived structures inherit virtual function `get_area()` so that `Triangle` normally calculates area but `Line` should give an error indicating that `get_area()` is not relevant to `Line`. When an error is shown I would like to know which structure called `get_area()` and where (line number) and finally terminate the program. It does not matter if the error shown in compile or run time. How can I do these?

```
struct Geometry
{
    virtual double get_area() = 0;
};

struct Triangle: Geometry
{
    double get_area() override {/* some code. */}
};

struct Line: Geometry
{
    double get_area() override {/* give error. */}
};
```

Comment: Maybe you need to rethink your design? Or your implementation at the very least? If lines doesn't have an area then the `Line` class should not *have* such a function?

Comment: Sounds like you need a `line` class that is a member of a `polygon` class and then you can derive from `polygon` to make your shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your keep your current design, despite the flaw explained by Joachim Pileborg:

A possible implementation for the method is:

```
double Triangle::get_area() override
{
    assert(false);
    return 0.;
}
```

Motivations:

In debug mode, `assert(condition);` will exit the program if the condition is false. Assuming your have your IDE & debugger, you'll be able to see who called the method.

However, in a regular release build, assertions are deactivated. `return 0.;` ensures something that makes sense is returned.
(Note: this may be changed by how you use the area value. NAN might be a good choice).

Notes:

- The issue will necessarily pops up at run time, because you are using virtual methods. This a design smell, that may be solved by several ways (defining the area of a line as 0, creating intermediary classes Shape1D and Shape2D, ...)
- Getting the caller, ie a call stack from code only is harder in C++ than languages like Java. Getting it is implementation-defined, as well as getting human-readable names of the methods. However, being in debug mode + having a debugger (which is the case with most IDE) allows you to do that painlessly.